# Post complex data from form. JS ==> ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, post, fetch-api

I have complex form with strings, files. And I'm adding to this form some JSON/object.In controller I can't handle my added object(Product) you can see it below.

Models

Model 1. MyData

```
    public string SomeThing { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Files { get; set; }
```

Model 2. Product

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public HttpStatusCodeResult GetData(MyData data) <== SomeThing-OK.Files-OK,Products-Products[0] 
    {
       //logic
    }
```

JS. I'm using Vue fetch API but it isn't a deal.The same thinks occurrence when I use JQuery.

```
    let form = new FormData(this.$refs.myForm);
    form.append('Products', [{ 'Id': 1, 'Count': 2 }])  <== In controller I always get Products[0] =(
    fetch('/GetData', {
            method: 'post',
            body: form
            })
          })
```

I'm totally confused. I don't want refuse using FormData(). I can easily handle files with it. But my controller doesn't see any complex(Products) object if I don't use JSON(stringify). I will be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Form data needs to be name/value pairs.

Comment: @pcalkins I did it. (name: 'Products', value: [{ 'Id': 1, 'Count': 2 }]